# using invoke in a class rather than in a form

Tags: vb.net

i wrote a program reading a com port for a signal, everything was working fine, but they wanted to make the application a service so i swapped the application type to 'windows service' and created a class and put everything in the form in there and i called the class in my Main() in the startup module. the line,

```
   Me.Invoke(New myDelegate(AddressOf UPdateVariable), New Object() {})
```

in the class has invoke in red saying that, "'Invoke, is not a member of Moisture.Moisture.'" and the "Me" part of that line is no longer greyed out as it was in the form. it worked before dont know what made the difference.

this is the whole code for that class

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Net.Mime

Public Class Moisture
    Dim WithEvents serialPort As New IO.Ports.SerialPort
Public Delegate Sub myDelegate()
Public RawString As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Public value As String

Public Sub StartListening()
    If serialPort.IsOpen Then
        serialPort.Close()
    End If

    Try
        With serialPort
            .PortName = "COM3"
            .BaudRate = 9600
            .Parity = Parity.None
            .StopBits = StopBits.One
            .DataBits = 8
            .Handshake = Handshake.None
            .RtsEnable = True
        End With
        serialPort.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

 Private Sub serialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort.DataReceived
    Me.Invoke(New myDelegate(AddressOf UPdateVariable), New Object() {})

End Sub

Public Sub UPdateVariable()
    With RawString
        .Append(serialPort.ReadLine())
    End With
    If RawString.ToString().Count(Function(x As Char) x = "%"c) = 2 Then
        PiTagUpdater(StringParser(RawString.ToString()))
        RawString.Clear()
    End If
End Sub

Public Function StringParser(RawString As String) As String
    Dim Moisture = RawString
    Dim value As String
    Dim values As String() = Moisture.Split(New Char() {":"c})
    value = values(values.Length - 1).Trim({" "c, "%"c})
    Return value
End Function

Private Sub PiTagUpdater(Value As Decimal)


    Try
        Dim piserver As New PCA.Core.PI.PIServer(PCA.Core.Globals.Applications.Application("GENERAL").ConfigValues.ConfigValue("PI_SERVER_NAME").StringValue, PCA.Core.Globals.Applications.Application("GENERAL").ConfigValues.ConfigValue("PI_SERVER_UID").GetDeCryptedStringValue, PCA.Core.Globals.Applications.Application("GENERAL").ConfigValues.ConfigValue("PI_SERVER_PASSWD").GetDeCryptedStringValue, True)
        Dim TimeStamp As DateTime = FormatDateTime(Now)
        Dim RapidRingCrush = "M1:RapidRingCrush.T"
        Try
            piserver.WriteValue(RapidRingCrush, Value, TimeStamp)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error occured locating Pi Tag", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Application.Exit()
        End Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to Pi Server")
    End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Me` refers to the current object, in this case the instance of your class. Your class doesn't have an `Invoke()` method (like the error says), though anything that derives from `System.Windows.Forms.Control` does (for instance a `Form`).

[**`Control.Invoke()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to move the execution of a method to the same thread that the control was created on. This is used to achieve thread-safety.

Since you switched to a service it is fair to assume that you do not have a user interface, thus there's no need to invoke. Removing the `Invoke()` call and calling the method manually should be enough:

```
Private Sub serialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort.DataReceived
    UPdateVariable()
End Sub
```

---

**EDIT:**

As LarsTech says, you also have to switch the message boxes to some kind of logging methods. A Windows Service usually runs under a different account, which means that it cannot display a user interface to the current user.

Comment: And those MessageBoxes need to be converted to logging methods, too.

Comment: @LarsTech : True, didn't think of them. Edited.

Comment: What was so bad about this, downvoter? I would like some constructive feedback.

Comment: the message boxes i was going to take off. i knew service has no UI, and great answer about the win forms package using into a class and didnt know about control.invoke usage, learned something today this was a very useful and enlightening answer thank you.

Comment: @VisualVincent i dont know who down voted but i gave you a positive vote so at least its at 0. thanks vincent

Comment: @Edgar : No problem, I'm glad I could help! And thank you :). -- You can also read a bit more about `Control.Invoke()` in my example on the [**Stack Overflow Documentation**](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vb.net/1913/threading/6235/performing-thread-safe-calls-using-control-invoke#t=201612101813487714004).